# Removing item from list - casting

Tags: java, android, list, adapter

In my `List` I'd like to remove an item: `v` is the button I clicked on.
I tagged the position with `holder.button1.setTag(position);`

Then, in the GetView's ClickListener :

```
Log.e("Tag", String.valueOf((Integer) v.getTag()));  //returns 2
data.remove((Integer) v.getTag()); //Does not remove the item
data.remove(2); //Removes it !!!!
```

Where is my error ?

EDIT :
Where

```
holder = new NewsHolder();
```

and

```
static class NewsHolder{

    TextView itemName;
    ImageView icon;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;


}
```

Comment: inside your getView provide position to your listener gridview.setOnClickListener(new onClick(position); then inside that listener use that position to remove.

Comment: have you tried data.remove(Integer.valueOf((Integer)v.getTag());

Comment: @Smartphone Developper That's allready done. the problem comes from the Integer casting (see comments)

Comment: @vkulla42 does not fix it :-(

Comment: and this? data.remove(Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()))) hope this solves it. Maybe you don't need the valueOf method, didn't tried it in my IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use int type rather than Integer which is an object unlike int type ?

Comment: You got it !!!
data.remove((int)((Integer)v.getTag())); solved the issue. Thanks :-)

Comment: To get your code easier, you can try this : data.remove(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag());

Comment: Eclipse shows an error with your last code. But Thanks for the other one :-)